# is there any alternate code for cross platform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

my project based on windows and now i convert it into Linux and Mc. Sp i wanna change this code for cross platform so it can work in all platform.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

---

```
public class Program
    {
        private const string DefaultInstallPath = @"C.....";
        private const string ProductRegistryKey = @"......";
        private static string _appPath;
        //....
}
```

---

```
public static string AppPath
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_appPath))
                {
                    var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

                    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                    {
                        _appPath = currentDirectory;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _appPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(ProductRegistryKey, "InstallPath", DefaultInstallPath);
                    }

                    if (_appPath == null)
                    {
                        _appPath = DefaultInstallPath;
                    }

                    if (!Directory.Exists(_appPath))
                    {
                        _appPath = currentDirectory;
                    }
                }
                return _appPath;            
            }
        }
```

i want that code which worked for all platform. so how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an application on asp.net core.

The core framework is created for multi platform development.

I don't know on what framework you are right now but i am assuming you are using .net framework.

Create an application from visual studio and select an application that is based on .net core framework. MVC, Console etc..

Essentially all the coding that you do on windows will theoretically work on linux because linux has its version of framework that can interpret the coding you do in windows.

Currently all multi platform development is done through C# core.

Hope that was helpful

Comment: i am converting my project from .net framework to .net core 3.1 and this code is related to updated .netcore3.1

Comment: Thats good man. 3.1 Is latest stable build of .net core. If I am not mistaken at this time. Of course to run it on linux you need to install the appropriate framework there. But usually people just create it as docker containers that can run in linux.
Dont forget to upvote the answer if it helped :D

Comment: ohk so can you give me that code, that help me for more understand your comment

Comment: You dont need to install asp.net core on linux. Developing on .net core should work on linux without problems. If you want to develop and run apps on linux then you need to install .net core 3.1 for linux. Microsoft. [Install page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download#linuxubuntu)
Developing on core 3.1 would enable you to add it on enviroments like nginx, apache docker based environments that are based on linux systems.
Think of it like JAVA. Develop on one OS and works on all OS
[This page](https://medium.com/wolox/how-to-create-your-first-net-e2223dedb74f) provides a simple guide

Comment: is there any thing else which replace this win32 or alternate of this win32 for cross platform

Comment: If i am not mistaken on asp.net core to access directory it is under namespace system.IO. Please upvote the answer if it was the solution to your problem.